# Does macosx Catalina always use clang by default?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, macos-catalina

I have osx catalina installed and when I type `gcc --version` I get the following:

```
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I am confused as to whether my code uses gcc when it compiles or clang when I type `gcc file.c -o file`

Answer (score 0):

It's using clang with a very outdated Standard Library. The built-in gcc is just an alias. If you want gcc, you can install it via homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

macOS does not come with GCC or Clang. Presumably you installed Xcode. Current versions of Xcode come with Clang and configure `gcc` to use Clang so that old scripts will still work.